# How do I match use regex to match multi-line text with specific starting and ending patterns

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, multiline

With the help of Python regex, I am trying to extract all the lines after [..] and starting with ;;  character. See example below

```
sample_str = '''[TITLE]

[OPTIONS]
;;Options            Value
;;------------------ ------------
FLOW_UNITS           CFS
<MORE TEXT>

[PATTERNS]
;;Name           Type       Multipliers
;;-------------- ---------- -----------
;Daily pattern generated from time series '2-166:2-165 (obs)'.  Average value was 0.0485 MGD.
2-166:2-165_(obs)_Daily DAILY      1.011 1.008 1.06  0.908 1.072 0.998 0.942
<MORE TEXT>

[COORDINATES]
;;Node           X-Coord          Y-Coord         
;;-------------- ---------------- ----------------
<MORE TEXT>

[JUNCTIONS]
;;               Invert     Max.       Init.      Surcharge  Ponded    
;;Name           Elev.      Depth      Depth      Depth      Area      
;;-------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
1-1              837.85     15.25      0          0          0         
<MORE TEXT>  

[REPORT]
INPUT      YES
CONTROLS   NO
<MORE TEXT>
'''
```

I would like to get a list like

```
expected_result = [';;Options            Value\n;;------------------ ------------', ';;Name           Type       Multipliers\n;;-------------- ---------- -----------', ..]
```

I was only able to get the first lines by `re.findall(r"(?<=\]\n);;.*", sample_str)`. Trying to add more lines pattern by adding `\n` like `re.findall(r"(?<=\]\n);;.*\n;;.*", sample_str, re.MULTILINE)` does not work since the pattern for texts I want is not uniform. I tried the using `re.multiline` to search for all the text until `-\n` but I could not get it to work as    `re.findall(r"(?<=\]\n);;.*-$", sample_str, re.MULTILINE)`.

Could someone help me with it!

Comment: From what I see there are no lines that start with `;;` that are *not* following a `[...]` section header. Would it still be correct when the condition is reduced to *"lines starting with `;;`"*?

Comment: So, you want all subsequent lines that start with `;;`? `re.findall(r'(?m)^;;.*(?:\n;;.*)*', text)`? Or `re.findall(r'(?m)^\[[^][]*]\n(;;.*(?:\n;;.*)*)', text)`?

Comment: @Tomalak, there are sections like [REPORT] or [TITLE] that do not have lines starting with ;; . If possible, an empty list would be preferred on those case.

Comment: These are the things that need to go into your question definition.

Comment: @Tomalak , thanks for suggestion. I don't think I have enough reputation for editing the question now!

Comment: You can always edit your own stuff. (Also, you *really* should make a performance comparison. The regex solution will be slower.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
re.findall(r"^\[.*\]\n+((?:;;.*\n+)+)", sample_str, re.M)
```

[Here is the explanation of the expression](https://regex101.com/r/NDQJjw/2)

*EDIT*: Added constraint for the pattern to start in the beginning of the line. Thanks for noticing @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: This pattern might match unwanted strings as the `[...]` can match anywhere on a line

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, this is easily possible without regex altogether:

```
input_str = '''...'''

flag = False
output = []

for line in input_str.splitlines():
    if not flag and line.startswith('[') and line.endswith(']'):
        flag = True
    elif flag and line.startswith(';;'):
        output.append(line)
    else:
        flag = False

print(output)
```

Note that the line endings would be missing because `.splitlines()` eats them.

---

If the input came from a file, it would be just as straight-forward:

```
def parse_file(filename):
    flag = False
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
        for line in f:
            if not flag and line.startswith('[') and line.endswith(']'):
                flag = True
            elif flag and line.startswith(';;'):
                yield line
            else:
                flag = False
```

Comment: I actually need to do it with regex. Actual file I work with are huge, and I feel regex might help me with the speed.

Comment: It won't. The above will be *significantly* faster than any regex solution (you can work with `yield` to speed this up even more).